# Is there a pithy phrase describing the state where two or more people are reduced to pointless, petty criticisms of each other?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a succinct way to describe what I believe is a semi-common situation, both in online discussions and sometimes in real life (e.g. with siblings during long car trips):  when a discussion between two or more people turns sour, such that rather than discussing or debating the subject at hand, the people involved get sufficiently irritated with each other that they instead get drawn into a back-and-forth series of pointless/petty/passive-aggressive criticisms of each others' style, grammar, minor logical ambiguities, etc.

I might call this "hen-pecking" (in reference to possibly-apocryphal reports that chickens packed into too-close proximity with each other will eventually start pecking each other to death, and must therefore either be given more space, or fitted with red contact lenses to calm them down), but I think there might be a better, more well-known phrase that describes the phenomenon.  Can anyone supply such a phrase?

Comment: Marriage?______

Comment: It has devolved to a *pissing contest*.

Comment: @Drew The phrase may seem related to "pissing and moaning" about something, but a pissing contest usually has some bone of contention, however petty.  The OP seems to be describing pointless bickering.

Comment: @deadrat: Yes, I know. But have you ever known a pissing contest to represent more than pointless bickering? It might start with a bone of contention, but by the time it has become a pissing contest the bone it typically long gone.

Comment: The point of bickering is the bickering.  It only seems pointless when you forget that.  Now let's have a good clean row.

Comment: You talkin' to me, @CandiedOrange? You talkin' to me? You talkin' to me? Well, who the hell else are you talkin' to? You talkin' to me? Well, I'm the only one here.   No, wait.  Everyone's here.  Er, never mind.

Comment: @Drew Hmm.  The answer depends on whether I've paid for the full hour.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is abuse.

Comment: "Discussing the meaning of [likely](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297766/the-usage-of-likely)."

Comment: Arguing? Whenever two or more people disagree about something and that discussion degenerates into a verbal fight, it's just called arguing/fighting/a shouting match. The term **bickering** which was first used by deadrat, seems the most appropriate here.

Comment: You can talk, you can talk, you can bicker
You can talk. You can bicker, bicker, bicker, you can talk
You can talk. You can talk, talk, talk, bicker, bicker, bicker.
You can talk all you wanna, but it's different than it was.
CHARLIE:
No it aint, no it aint, but you gotta know the territory.

Comment: "a back-and-forth series of pointless/petty/passive-aggressive criticisms of each others' style, grammar, minor logical ambiguities, etc."? For most of the internet, that's called a "comment section".... :P

Comment: Squabble? Pissing contest? Pfft. We are clearly talking about none else than a [squirmish](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=squirmish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "bickering" especially when those doing it are married or siblings.

Comment: Your term is apt, but your answer should have a citation or an example sentence.

Answer (score 0):

squabble is more emphasis on 'noisy', but does represent trivial quibbles.

Comment: You mean like double-trouble trebled quibble squabbles?

Answer (score 0):

What I gather from the post seems to suggest CROSSTALK or XIANGSHENG meaning undesirable talk incidental to the topic of discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It stretches the traditional definition, but you could call it ***mudslinging***.  To update it for the modern day internet, you could perhaps call it ***shitslinging*** and people would know exactly what you mean.

My first thought here, with regards to when this happens online, is the aphorism, *"Never wrestle with a pig.  You both get dirty and the pig likes it."* It's a situation where both parties have ended up wallowing in the muck.

It's far more common to say the conversation has degenerated into *slinging* insults.  But since you are looking for a description of the state, I'd say things have reached the point of *mudslinging* or *shitslinging*.

Answer (score -1):

To borrow from other ugly spectacles:

*cage match* — the combatants have no way out

*sparring*   — competitive training

Comment: A cage match implies a brawl, not a pointless, petty argument. Sparring is associated with fencing and the pointed blows that come with it. Neither are appropriate to describe last-resort ad hominem attacks.